# Screen media recording android

Tags: android

Actually I'm developping an android application that needs to record a single surface from screen. I used MediaProjectionManager but the problem it records the whole screen.

Any ideas how can I record a single surface ( videoview for example ) ?

Thanks

Comment: The media projection APIs are for recording the content of arbitrary apps. You have no means of accessing a `VideoView` in somebody else's app.

Comment: It means that it's impossible to record a single surface in my activity ?

Comment: You cannot use the media projection APIs to record a single surface in your activity. I have no idea if there is another solution.